# How to pause KafkaJS consumer and retry after sometime

Tags: error-handling, apache-kafka, consumer, pause, kafkajs

I'm using KafkaJS ( https://kafka.js.org ) to connect to a Kafka cluster. My consumers are responsible for processing tasks which can fail at some time and succeed after waiting for a duration (for example, 1 hour).
Before this duration, any attempt to process any task will result to another failure.

I tried to use Pause & Resume method as described at https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-pause-resume-a-pause-resume. However, the consumer restart immediately and keep consuming the failed task again.

How can I pause consuming messages without committing a failed one and restarting the consumer immediately?